# Is it Possible to serve a Client Side React Component / Application in a server side Express Route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, pug, create-react-app

I have an Node/Express backend that is using Pug.js to render a number of server side routes. The application is static at the moment and is a simple site.

I created an interactive "builder" component in React.js using CRA. It allows a site visitor to configure product interactively. 
The end goal is this:

when a site visitor hits the builder nav link, they would be taken to a page that would render my serverside templates to keep the look and feel of the site. However, In the content block I would want to render the react application that I have created.

I have looking for days and maybe am just not understanding what I am seeing.I am not sure if server side rendering, or proxying would make this work? i have tried the CRA proxy and have not gotten the result.

Folder structure image:

[image: Folder Structure]

If anyone needs more info or can point out a few resources it would be very helpful.

I am still learning as well so I apologize if this breaks any SO guidelines.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, you are using a templating engine for most routes, but for one route you want to load a react app, and you want to use SSR (server side rendering)?

Comment: Do you have it working when the React app is rendered on the client? I’d shoot for that first, then work on SSR. This question is relevant https://stackoverflow.com/q/37895635/3518108

Comment: Sam, thank you for questions. Yes it is working when React app is rendering on the client.  As for the clarification.  I want To do what works . All of the static site routes are rendering server side using Pug as the view engine and the public directory to serve static assets. What I am Not clear on is two things. Firstly if I need To use SSR to achieve the desired functionality or not? Secondly and if not what is the best way to serve the React app in an Express router endpoint? I just Wish to have the React app render inside of the pug view as a block so as to maintain my templates.

Comment: Does this clarify my question?

Comment: Also thanks for the link. I will Look into it

Comment: Are you compiling your react? Since JSX isn't something the browser can read, one usually sets up Babel or Webpack or Gulp or something to transform it into regular Javascript. I don't see a directory called `build` or anything in your screenshot... so step one is to compile your JSX, then step two is to do something like `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));`

Comment: Sam - Does CRA not handle the build and bundling under the hood as long as the eject is not performed?

Comment: Totally forgot you were using CRA. Have you run `npm run build`? that should make a `build` folder and put the compiled JS in there, which you can serve with express

Comment: So am I to understand that for that one component I would just Pinot the express route to the public resource. Or would an approach be to pull the component from the public folder into my pug template? Are either of these the right ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your CRA looks something like

```
  import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM  from 'react-dom';

    ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

So to expose this component, you should have a pug template that is like all your others, except also contains somewhere in it

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Where the src of the script is the relative path to your built component. Then just serve that template with express when they hit that route.

Comment: This clarifies things for me tremendously. Thank you so much for seeing me through. 

Comment: No problem. This end up with the rest component being rendered on the client but the react runtime. A fun exercise would be to server side render this. To do that, I'd look into Next.js which is a nice SSR framework for react

Comment: I have actually already been digging into this over the past few days. I am at the moment using Redux. Managing server side is quite the challenge. I have not looked at next.js yet but I will for sure. Thank you again man!