# I'm trying to render a react component on DOM node, defined in a pug file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**Background Information**

The basic structure of my initial application was

main.pug

```
... code elements ...
<div  class = "panel">
... code elements ...
```

and a starter javascript file that is loaded in the header, which contains this block of code

starter.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ... logic to determine html page to show in the panel div ...
  ... it determines the name and saves it in the variable 'htmlPageToShow' ...

  $(".panel").load(htmlPageToShow);
});
```

this bit of code in starter.js is how content is displayed in the panel div
it determines the file name and then loads it into the dom element

**Problem**

I decided that i wanted to have React handle this part, my conclusion was to render a React component called  into the panel div, in hopes of improving this bit of the code without having to change the entire code base but two days in, and I cannot get a react component, or html element of any kind, to render in the div, similar to how html pages were loaded

**My attempts**

I left the main.pug file alone and in starter.js, did this:

starter.js

```
import react from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import PanelHandler from './PanelHandler';

ReactDom.render(
  <PanelHandler/>,
  document.getElementById('panel'));
```

I've tried multiple versions of this, such as replacing the get element id bit with `$(".panel")` I've tried using `getElementByClassName`, `QuerySelector`, I've tried using `window.document`

I've also tried putting the whole thing into a script tag and appending it to the end of main.pug

At some point, I tried creating a new html page, with the code above in a script tag, and then loading that into panel, with the previous logic, all to no avail

I want to know if I'm missing something, can pug just not be used with React? am I missing a dependency? any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: There might be more to your problem, but two things look fishy here.  1. `$(.panel)`  should be `$(".panel")`.  You are trying to get a class called "panel" yet... 2. you are trying to find it by id in your render function.

Comment: My mistake, the first problem was just a typo on my part, as for your second point, I also tried document.getElementByClassName but that didn't work either. 
The objective seems relatively easy, I'm surprised it turned out so hard to accomplish

My current theory is that it has something to do with trying to use pug and React in the same code base?

Comment: might these articles will help you https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2796, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895635/can-i-use-pug-ex-jade-with-react-framework/49432823

Comment: thank you! I'll look at these and see how it can be applied!